# The symbol you provided is not a function

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

---

**Key points before reading further**

1. All variables are properly var'ed (you'll have to trust me)
2. Scopes *are not* being reset while these long-running processes are happening
3. When dumping the metadata for the supposedly missing/invalid method, I get the right information
4. There are only two places where the name of this method are referenced in the application. Once where it's defined, and once were the method is called in the code below.

---

I have a very strange intermittent error that I can't seem to track down. Here's the background (these are severely trimmed down to simplify for posting).

FeedService.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" extends="FeedDAO">

    <cffunction name="processXmlFile" access="public" output="false" returntype="struct">
        <cfset Var local = StructNew() />

/***************************************
THE VARIABLES ARE ALL VAR'D - PROMISE!!!
Lots of other stuff goes on in here to get the ultimate set of XML nodes to loop through
*****************************************/

        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(local.arrChannels)#" index="local.currentChannelItem">
            ... Lots of XML parsing and stuff and things going on here ...

            <cfset LOCAL.invCheck = checkCustomerListing(
                Acct_ID = local.invStruct.AcctID
                , CustomerListingID = local.invStruct.CustomerListingID
            ) />

            ... Lots more stuff going on here ...

        </cfloop>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

FeedDAO:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <cffunction name="checkCustomerListing" access="public" output="false" returntype="numeric" hint="Returns the numeric inventory ID for an existing inventory listing, or 0 if the listing doesn't exist.">
        <cfargument name="Acct_ID" type="numeric" required="true" hint="" />
        <cfargument name="CustomerListingID" type="string" required="true" hint="" />
        <cfset var rs = "">

        <cfquery name="rs" datasource="#Variables.DSNs.Primary#">
            SELECT ID FROM TheTable
            WHERE
                Acct_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.Acct_ID#" />
                AND Customer_Listing_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Arguments.CustomerListingID#" />
        </cfquery>

        <cfif rs.RecordCount>
            <cfreturn rs.Inv_ID />
        <cfelse>
            <cfreturn 0 />
        </cfif>

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

I'm calling the initial function like so:

```
<cfset processStruct = Server.FeedService.processXmlFile(filePath) />
```

So, when a feed gets submitted to the processXMLFile function, it looks through all of the items in the file. A feed file may have 10, 100, or even 1000 entries. I get occasional error messages like this while a file is getting processed:

```
[struct]
Detail: The symbol you provided checkCustomerListing is not the name of a function.
Message: Entity has incorrect type for being called as a function.
StackTrace: coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$UninvocableEntityException: Entity has incorrect type for being called as a function.
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2441)
    at coldfusion.runtime.SuperScope.invoke(SuperScope.java:18)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2222)
```

More stack dump information

```
    Type: Application
    symbolName: checkCustomerListing

    [object of coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$UninvocableEntityException]
    Class Name: coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$UninvocableEntityException
    Fields: 
        java.lang.String symbolName: checkCustomerListing
    Parent Class: [object of coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationException]
        Class Name: coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationException
        Parent Class: [object of coldfusion.runtime.NeoException]
            Class Name: coldfusion.runtime.NeoException
            Methods:  
                findAdvancedCFTarget(coldfusion.runtime.AdvancedCFException, java.lang.String[]) returns int 
                findCustomTarget(coldfusion.runtime.CustomException, java.lang.String[]) returns int 
                findThrowableTarget(java.lang.Throwable, java.lang.String[]) returns int 
                getDetail() returns java.lang.String 
                getLocalizedMessage() returns java.lang.String 
                getMessage() returns java.lang.String 
                getRootCause() returns java.lang.Throwable 
                getString(java.lang.Throwable, java.lang.String, java.util.Locale) returns java.lang.String 
                getType() returns java.lang.String 
                setLocale(java.util.Locale) returns void 
                unwrap(java.lang.Throwable) returns java.lang.Throwable
            Parent Class: [object of java.lang.RuntimeException]
                Class Name: java.lang.RuntimeException
                Parent Class: [object of java.lang.Exception]
                    Class Name: java.lang.Exception
                    Parent Class: [object of java.lang.Throwable]
                        Class Name: java.lang.Throwable
                        Methods:  
                            fillInStackTrace() returns java.lang.Throwable 
                            getCause() returns java.lang.Throwable 
                            getLocalizedMessage() returns java.lang.String 
                            getMessage() returns java.lang.String 
                            getStackTrace() returns java.lang.StackTraceElement[] 
                            initCause(java.lang.Throwable) returns java.lang.Throwable 
                            printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter) returns void 
                            printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream) returns void 
                            printStackTrace() returns void 
                            setStackTrace(java.lang.StackTraceElement[]) returns void 
                            toString() returns java.lang.String
```

I may get one error in 1000 entries, or I may get a small batch of errors at one time, and the rest of the feed processes just fine (due to some try/catch logic to prevent the entire thing from crapping out). At one point, the `checkCustomerListing` was in a completely different Server scoped object, and I never had a problem. I moved it into the `FeedDAO` and started calling it via the Super scope, and that's when these intermittent errors began.

*UPDATE*: I have everything properly var'ed, I just chopped it all out for the sake of brevity.

*UPDATE AGAIN*: Changed code sample comments to make it clear that there is *a lot* of stuff going on before the first loop begins, including setting all LOCAL variables that will be used in the loop.

*More Code Information*:
I should note that there are only two places in our entire application (thousands upon thousands of lines of code) where the string 'checkCustomerListing' exists. One is where the function is called, and two is where the function is declared. There are no other instances of the string `checkCustomerListing` anywhere.

**Update: 6 September, 2011**

I added some additional error checking to see if I could find out what the app thought `checkCustomerListing` was (thanks Adam and Ryan). Here's my new try/catch statement:

```
<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfset local.tmpError.cfcatch = cfcatch>

    <cfif isDefined("checkCustomerListing")>
        <cfset local.tmpError.customerListing = checkCustomerListing />
        <cfset local.tmpError.customerListingMeta = getMetaData(checkCustomerListing) />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset local.tmpError.customerListing = "Checkcustomerlisting is not defined" />
    </cfif>

    <cfset Server.Utilities.Errors.emailCaughtError(local.tmpError)>

</cfcatch>
```

So I got an error this morning, and in the email I received, there is no `customerListing` node in the dump, but there is a meta node:

```
CUSTOMERLISTINGMETA:  
    [struct]
    ACCESS: public
    HINT: Returns the numeric inventory ID for an existing inventory listing, or 0 if the listing doesn't exist.
    NAME: checkCustomerListing
    OUTPUT: false
    PARAMETERS:  
        [array]
        1) [struct]
            HINT: [empty string]
            NAME: Acct_ID
            REQUIRED: true
            TYPE: numeric 
        2) [struct]
            HINT: [empty string]
            NAME: CustomerListingID
            REQUIRED: true
            TYPE: string 
    RETURNTYPE: numeric
```

All of that meta information is *exactly* correct... so if it can find the metadata for the function, why can't it find the function itself?

Comment: I don't know if it's part of your post cutdown but where is local.arrChannels being declared?

Comment: Can you tell us what version of ColdFusion you're running. Some comments refer to varring but if you're running ColdFusion 9 then local is a valid scope and doesn't require any.

Comment: James, the question is already tagged "coldfusion-8" which should give a small clue as to what version Dan is using. ;)

Comment: Through an XML parse at the beginning of the function. The only issue is that it thinks a function doesn't exist. If I had undeclared variables, it would never even make it down to the problem section.

Comment: Peter's right, CF8, and I do have all variables declared. I'll update the code some more to make that more clear.

Comment: Have you tried to do a dump on checkCustomerListing somewhere in your error handling to see exactly what it checkCustomerListing is when the error is being thrown?  It definitely sounds like something is affecting the something in the variables that points to that function.

Comment: Good call on adding the dump in there. I'll do that and see what it comes up with.

Comment: Dan, that extra telemetry doesn't suggest anything to me.  Can you do me a favour? Can you shift that CFC instance into the application scope instead (don't copy it from the server scope; create a new instance of it in the application scope).  I just wanna see what happens if you run from the application scope instead.

Comment: I've discovered that I *was* getting this error on my local development machine, I just wasn't getting the email notification due to a bad local configuration. So now I can reproduce this locally on my dev machine... time for more digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing super.checkCustomerListing? You would only do that if you overrode the function in your service and wanted to run the 'parent'. Just call checkCustomerListing().

Comment: I'll give this a try, not sure how that would fix the issue though. Shouldn't `Super` *always* exist? Whether I use the `Super` scope or not, it  should always be there.

Comment: Whilst it's good advice, it's nowt to do with this issue, is it?

Comment: That's exactly to do with the issue, I just don't see how that could fix it. The problem is specifically that the child object is *losing* a hook to the `checkCustomerListing` function in the parent object it's extending...

Comment: That's not the error you'd get if that'd somehow happened though, you'd just get "The checkCustomerListing  method was not found".  Although that said, obviously something not-obvious is happening here, so I s'pose one ought to expect "unexpected behaviour".

Comment: So - did you remove super.checkCustomerListing()? I see you still have it.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer now. I removed the `super` reference yesterday morning and haven't seen an error since. I don't' know why this is the solution, and it seems to me that it *shouldn't* be a solution, but it's working. I'll keep an eye on it for the next few days and if it crops up again come back to this question. Thanks.

Comment: I have a CFC called `Comment.cfc` that extends `Model`. The `Comment` class implements a method called `createActivity()` that does some processing and calls `super.createActivity()`.

`Model.cfc` implements its own `createActivity()`.

I get the same error that you're describing, and it only occurs periodically as well. Looks like some sort of bug with CF. This answer may solve the problem for you, but it looks like it will not solve the problem for my scenario.

Answer (score 7):

This usually crops up as a result of lack of VARing as others have alluded to.  Quite often people have a private function called "getStuff" and within that they have a query called "getStuff".  If the variable isn't VARed, then the getStuff query result goes into the CFC's variables scope, which will overwrite the function getStuff because that also resides in the variables scope.

So check your usage of checkCustomerListing for any same-named variables that aren't VARed (or in the local scope).

(and note that the checkCustomerListing variables don't need to be within the same method for this to happen... it could be anywhere in the CFC or any extending or super CFCs...)

Comment: Good point, but I do indeed have everything declared, and this problem only happens in small batches during the processing of a much larger file. Out of 1000 loops through a feed, it may error on only one item, or it may error on 10 in a row. The number of errors will even change from one call to another, processing the same file each time.

Comment: Hmmm.  And is this in a lab environment where this is the only request running?  Or could something else be interferring?

Comment: This is in a production environment, where there may be other things running at the same time. However, all of the pieces here are very self-contained. It seems to me that CF is losing a reference to the function, but I don't have any clue how to tell how that might be happening.

Comment: So you can't replicate this in dev?

Comment: I haven't seen the issue on my local dav system. I just processed a 7.8 meg XML file twice in a row and didn't see any problems. I even attempted processed the same file at the same time through two separate threads, and still didn't see the issue...

Comment: I wonder if copied the Server scoped CFC into a local variable, and then called the function through that if it would get rid of the error...

Comment: I tried to be sneaky and create a server-scoped CFC which ran a method, childMethod(), which in turn called a super method, superMethod(), but between calling childMethod() from the calling code and childMethod() making its call to superMethod(), I replaced the server-scoped CFC instance with a different CFC.  Predictably - I guess - CF/Java ain't that dumb and this caused no problems.  Still racking my brains...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3068/discussion-between-adam-cameron-and-dan-short)

Answer (score 1):

It may be in your abridged code but are you validating that local.invStruct.AcctID and local.invStruct.CustomerListingID both exist and are of the proper types?  Sometimes in Java "function doesn't exist" means "method signature doesn't exist".  I am not sure when CF validates datatypes but if you are looping over the same two variables if might be shortcutting and not validating the types in later loops.

Might also toss a val() on the return value just in case.

Comment: Nice idea there, but yes, both variables are declared. In the error email I receive, I have the entire `instruct` variable dumped, and both `AcctID` and `customerListingID` are in there :/

Comment: Still might be worth tossing a val in a couple of spots. Might not resolve the problem, but isn't gonna hurt.

Comment: True, certainly couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

i've seen this before when you have an object cached in a scope that is taking a while to run and you either overwrite or remove the object in the cache. my guess is this is what is happening, another application is doing something to the object in the cache and it's casuing the other applications to trip over each other.

a good way to test this is to duplicate the object cached in the server scope to a local variable and then use that local variable to run your process:

```
<cfset _feedservice = duplicate(Server.FeedService)>
<cfset processStruct = _feedservice.processXmlFile(filePath) />
```

now even if the object in the server scope gets overwritten or removed, you still have a copy of the original object that your process will use. it also won't be a bad idea to use locks around the above code:

```
<cflock scope="server" timeout="5" type="readonly">
<cfset _feedservice = duplicate(Server.FeedService)>
<cfset processStruct = _feedservice.processXmlFile(filePath) />
</cflock>
```

now personally an even better practice (in my opinion) would be to add something to your onApplicationOnStart() event that will copy all the objects that you are caching to the server scope into the application scope. the only reason i can see anyone ever using the server scope is because you want all the applications on the server sharing the same objects. doing this will still allow your applications to share the same code, but will prevent other applications from accidentally tripping over each other

Comment: That's a good call as far as describing the symptoms, but in this case, this is *the only* application on the server... That being said, this is a long-running application, so it's possible it still has something to do with that. I added some additional debugging at the suggestion of Adam, and once I get some more information from that, I'll most likely follow your suggestion as my next step.

Comment: I had the same thought, and tried to replicate it.  I contrived a test that server-scoped a CFC instance of C.cfc which extended SuperC.cfc, creating a method in C.cfc which took 10sec to run (by putting a sleep() in it), before calling a super-scoped method.  During the 10sec, I killed the CFC instance in the server scope.  The method completed fine.  So I instead recreated the server-scoped instance as a new instance of the same CFC: it still didn't break. Then I recreated it as an instance of a completely different CFC: still no problem.  Java is too smart to allow this to be a problem.