# Coldfusion, The symbol you provided [method_name] is not a function

Tags: coldfusion, components

Running CF 9,0,1,274733

I have a custom DAO CFC with a method called getGamesBetTypesID().

The method is generated/synthesized implicitly by CF from the following property:

```
<cfproperty name="gamesBetTypesID" type="numeric" />
```

A default variable is defined as follows:

```
<cfset VARIABLES.gamesBetTypesID = 0 />
```

Other than that there are no other VARIABLES, vars, LOCALs, ARGUMENTS or methods called getGamesBetTypesID. All CFC and function variables are correctly scoped.

This save() method is called thousands of times, but the following error gets thrown randomly and only a handful of times.

```
Detail: The symbol you provided getGamesBetTypesID is not the name of a function. 
Message: Entity has incorrect type for being called as a function.
```

Here's the save() method:

```
<cffunction name="save" access="public" returntype="void" output="false">

    <cfif getGamesBetTypesID() eq 0 or getGamesBetTypesID() eq "">
        <cfset create() />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset update() />
    </cfif>

</cffunction>
```

When the error gets thrown I log a dump of the CFCs metadata using 
getMetaData(gamesBetTypesObj). According to the meta data the function getGamesBetTypesID does exist.

Has anybody else some across this before? I've read that it can happen due to naming and scope collisions, of which I have none.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the exact same error, which only happens under load. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272498/the-symbol-you-provided-is-not-a-function Didn't really find a good answer for it, though my situation is slightly different than yours.

Comment: Hi Jason, don't really want to post the whole thing. I just updated to show the method that it's failing on.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for that. I read through your post before posting mine. Slightly different situation, but yeah, it only appears under load. Very frustrating.

Comment: are you using `accessor="True"`? or `persistent="true"`?

Comment: Henry, using accessors="true".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting the question above I removed `<cfproperty name="gamesBetTypesID" type="numeric" />` and added an explicit getter and setter for `VARIABLES.gamesBetTypesID`.

```
<cffunction name="getGamesBetTypesID" output="false" access="public" returntype="numeric">
    <cfreturn VARIABLES.gamesBetTypesID />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setGamesBetTypesID" output="false" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="gamesBetTypesID" required="true" type="numeric" />
    <cfset VARIABLES.gamesBetTypesID = ARGUMENTS.gamesBetTypesID />
</cffunction>
```

This code has been running in production for a week, including a weekend, which is our busy period. Not one exception has been thrown in the last 7 days. Previously, up to 15 exceptions were being thrown on a busy day.

This leads me to believe that there is a bug in the generation/use of implicit accessors by way of `<CFPROPERTY>` that only appears in certain situations. I'm going to log a bug with [Adobe](http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html)

I'll update if any progress is made.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a very old question.  I had the same situation pop up but my function was explicitly named (no cfproperty or get/set).  The issue was that I had a local variable declared within my function using the same name as my function.  My function was called from within a loop.  If the function was only called once, no issue.  If the function was called a second time, I would receive the same error you received.  I suspect when the local variable was created it would wipe out the function definition due to the naming collision.  I renamed my local variable and the issue disappeared.