# coldfusion - Entity has incorrect type for being called as a function

Tags: coldfusion

I have a situation where I'm refactoring some code - I segregated out a lot of code in a loop and put it into a component, each activity is a method, all called w/i a loop.

when it runs - the second time thru the loop, it fails to resolve a.id - at line "var b = b( i, a.id );"

If i do a writeOutput() at each line, I see my vals at the start of the loop and at each line, until the last time.

```
    function a() {
        //do thing
        return id;
    }

    function b() {
        //do thing
        return id;
    }

    function bigOne() {
        for( var i=1; i<2; i++; ) {
            var a = a( i );
            var b = b( i, a.id );
        }
    }
```

Ive tried this too - same issue

```
function bigOne() {
    var a = '';
    var b = '';

    for( var i=1; i<2; i++; ) {
        a = a( i );
        b = b( i, a.id );
    }
}
```

I've read this [Coldfusion, The symbol you provided [method_name] is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689204/coldfusion-the-symbol-you-provided-method-name-is-not-a-function) - but it's not the same thing, this article is dealing with getters and setters... I don't think this applies to my issue.

If I put my output like this (to 'see' it):

```
function bigOne() {
    var loopcount = 1;
    for( var i=1; i<2; i++; ) {
        writeOutput( 'loop count = ' & loopcount );
        var a = a( i );
        writeoutput( 'a.id = ' & a.id );
        var b = b( i, a.id );
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
loop count = 1
a.id = 52978
loop count = 2
```

then error. ERROR MSG:  Entity has incorrect type for being called as a function.
The symbol you provided insStop is not the name of a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions are pointed to by references just like variables are, so when you do this:

```
a = a();
```

you are overwriting the reference that points to the function `a` with the value returned from it.  So the next time you try to call `a()`, `a` ia no longer your function, it is the value returned from it the previous time it was called.

When you get an error along the lines of a variable not being able to be used in the way you want to use it... *dump it out and look at what it contains*. That generally points you in the right direction as to what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To support what Adam says, you can avoid this by scoping your variables inside your function. By default, unscoped variables are placed in the "variables" scope and this applies to functions called within the same template. So instead of naming your function var "loopcount", you could scope it to the "local" scope i.e

```
var local.loopcount = 1
```

This will make the function var belong only to the function and thus unaffected by anything occurring outside the function and vice-versa.

Comment: Since `local` is a full fledged system scope in CF9+, best to use `var` OR `local` - not both.